The playwright-python is clickable but nothing happen
with sync_playwright() as p:
     browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
     page = browser.new_page()
     page.goto('https://ctrl.unruly.co/auth/login')
     page.fill('input[id="email"]', username)
     page.fill('input[id="password"]',password)
     result = solveRecaptcha(
         sitekey=sitekey,
         url=url
     )
     code = result['code']
        
     page.evaluate(f"""() => {{
         var token = '{code}';
         var callbackFunction = ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients['0']['F']['F']['callback'];
         callbackFunction(token);

     }}""")
     page.wait_for_selector("button#submit:not([disabled]):not([tabindex])",state='attached')

     page.screenshot(path="debug_screenshot.png")

     page.click('button#submit:not([disabled]):not([tabindex])')

     page.screenshot(path="debug_screenshot2.png")

This is my script using playwrigth-python, the website has a recaptcha callback. I bypass all of those flawlessly, the 'Sign In' button appear but it is unclickable. Actually it is clickable because when I run the script with 'headless=false', I saw that it is performing the 'page.click' but it did not go to the homepage. Usually if we press the sign in button it will immediately go to the homepage of the website.
The element before the sign in button appear are shown like this:
<button _ngcontent-ng-c3870558994="" nz-button="" nzsize="large" nztype="primary" nzblock="" id="submit" class="ant-btn primary-button ng-tns-c630436078-2 ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg ant-btn-block" tabindex="-1" disabled="true"><!----><span class="ng-star-inserted"> Sign In </span></button>
And the element after the sign in button appear are shown like this:
<button _ngcontent-ng-c3870558994="" nz-button="" nzsize="large" nztype="primary" nzblock="" id="submit" class="ant-btn primary-button ng-tns-c630436078-2 ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg ant-btn-block"><!----><span class="ng-star-inserted"> Sign In </span></button>
As you can see the two attributes in the HTML will be deleted once the sign in button appear, the 2 attributes tabindex="-1" disabled="true".
I feel like Ive done correctly, but I need some one pov on this. Your help will be mush appreciated.
Once you click it will go to the homepage but this is not doing that.
I tried to put page.goto(to the homepage) under the page.click but it kick me back to the login page

I don't have your captcha solver, but did you try a force click or dispatching a native untrusted click?

I tried the force click but it still the same. This is the first time I hear about dispatching a native untrusted click. Can you tell me more about it? Is it under playwright? I might take a look and return back to you if I made progress

page.click('button#submit:not([disabled]):not([tabindex])').evaluate("el => el.click()"). Make sure the element isn't in a shadow DOM or iframe and that you're actually on the site you think you are.

@ggorlen I think I fixed by adding a parameter in page.click('#submit' , delay=5000). Still idk if the delay is in ms or not
